# Use geoJson Leaflet with Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, leaflet, geojson

I would like to use leaflet with Dart and I don't know how to do.

I tried using invokeMethod but it seems doesn't work with static function.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any Js library from Dart.

See [Using JavaScript from Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/).

Comment: Okay, but i would like to use Dart and not JS library, is it possible ?

Comment: AFAIK http://leafletjs.com/ is a Js library that does not have a Dart port. So you have to use it from Dart according to the article I pointed out.